# Error on Azure Authentication in PHP

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0, magento2

I am getting following error in Azure Authentication. Kindly help me understand the same.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException'
> with message 'invalid_client' in
> /var/www/html/active/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php:216
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/active/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(644):
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider->checkResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
> Array) #1
> /var/www/html/active/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(560):
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/active/src/Delegates/Receive.php(82): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken('authorization_c...',
>
> Array) #3 /var/www/html/active/src/ActiveDirectory.php(180):
> Magium\ActiveDirectory\Delegates\Receive->execute() #4
> /var/www/html/active/index.php(25):
> Magium\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory->authenticate() #5 {main}
> thrown in
> /var/www/html/active/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php
> on line 216

I have the following code

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$config = [
    'authentication' => [
        'ad' => [
            'client_id' => 'xxx',
            'client_secret' => 'xxx',
            'enabled' => '1',
            'directory' => 'common'
        ]
    ]
];

$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();

$ad = new \Magium\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory(
    new \Magium\Configuration\Config\Repository\ArrayConfigurationRepository($config),
    Zend\Psr7Bridge\Psr7ServerRequest::fromZend(new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request())
);

$entity = $ad->authenticate();

echo $entity->getName() . '<Br />';
// echo $entity->getOid() . '<Br />';
echo $entity->getPreferredUsername() . '<Br />';
```

URL : https://github.com/magium/active-directory

Kindly help.

Comment: are you trying to get `access_token`?which crm are you using?

Comment: I m trying use Microsoft authentication API for Login and i am getting this error. Please refer https://github.com/magium/active-directory

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft automatically signs in using the client id which is used first time. If it is a wrong one, it will always throw this error even if it is updated in `.env` file. How to overcome this?

1. Go to [Apps & Services](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage) page
2. Click on *Edit* against the app you are trying to sign in
3. Click on *Remove these permissions* button
4. Try to authenticate again